# Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200> when using get :edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise

## I have a problem with redirecting and testing it in rspec

I have a problem with test not passing when I use a get method, but are green for the same code base when I use a put method. I don't know how to work around this and need assistance in making tests pass.

I get a `200 HTTP` status code, but I want to get confirmation on redirect, so that it could be tracked by `rspec`. What code basically needs to do is redirect logged in user who is not owner of a product to `category_product_url(category, product)` with a flash `error: 'You are not allowed to edit this product.'` when trying to edit product with `get http method`.

Used gems `rspec-rails`, `devise` and `decent_exposure`. Ruby `2.1.5` and Rails `4.1.8`

Actual error message:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(category_product_url(category, product))
   Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>

Failure/Error: expect(controller.flash[:error]).to eq 'You are not allowed to edit this product.'
   
   expected: "You are not allowed to edit this product."
        got: nil
   
   (compared using ==)
```

My spec

```
context 'another user is singed in' do
let(:user) { create(:user) }
let(:user2) { build(:user) }
let(:product) { Product.create! valid_attributes }

before do
  sign_in user2
  controller.stub(:user_signed_in?).and_return(true)
  controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(user2)
  controller.stub(:authenticate_user!).and_return(user2)
  product.user = user
end

describe 'GET edit' do
  describe 'with valid params' do
    it 'redirects to product page' do
      get :edit, { id: product.to_param, category_id: category.to_param }
      expect(response).to redirect_to(category_product_url(category, product))

    end

    it 'renders error message' do
      get :edit, { id: product.to_param, category_id: category.to_param }
      expect(controller.flash[:error]).to eq 'You are not allowed to edit this product.'
    end
  end
end
```

My controller

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy, :create]
expose(:category)
expose(:products)
expose(:product)

def edit
end

def update
  if product.user == current_user
    if self.product.update(product_params)
      redirect_to category_product_url(category, product), notice: 'Product was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  else
     redirect_to category_product_url(category, product), flash: { error: 'You are not allowed to edit this product.' } 
  end
end

private
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price, :category_id, :user_id)
end
```

What is strange, is that put method is working fine with the same `update` action. Following specs are passing

```
describe 'PUT update' do
  describe 'with valid params' do
    it 'redirects to product page' do
      put :update, { id: product.to_param, product: { 'title' => 'MyString' }, category_id: category.to_param }
      expect(response).to redirect_to(category_product_url(category, product))
    end

    it 'does not update product' do
      put :update, { id: product.to_param, product: { 'title' => 'MyNewString' }, category_id: category.to_param }
      expect(controller.product.title).to_not eq 'MyNewString'
    end

    it 'renders error message' do
      put :update, { id: product.to_param, product: { 'title' => 'MyString' }, category_id: category.to_param }
      expect(controller.flash[:error]).to eq 'You are not allowed to edit this product.'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it's ok to use put method for update action since you are updating a record after edit.

Comment: It's not a problem, as I mentioned this tests are passing. What I need to do is to get the `get` tests to pass without breaking the `put` tests.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. There is no code for "edit" in the controller. Why would you expect calling get "edit" to do anything but render the edit page (and return 200)?

Comment: this is how [decent_exposure](http://decentexposure.info/index.html) gem works

Answer (score 1):

The way how `decent_exposure` and `devise` work, you need to first invoke a `before_action` method passing there a private method of your choice.

For this particular example your controller should contain this

```
before_action :author!, only: [:edit, :update]
```

and a private method filter

```
def author!
  unless self.product.user == current_user
    redirect_to category_product_url(category, product),
      flash: { error: 'You are not allowed to edit this product.' }
  end
end
```

This way you get your `get http requests` and `put http requests` pass the specs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
expect(:get => "/products/1/edit").to route_to(:controller => "controller_name", :action => "action_name")
```

Hope this will work.